# Can I renew visitor visa while in Canada, visit the US and return to Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, standard-visitor-visas

I have a visitor visa which expires on 14 April 2017. However, I am currently in Canada, as I arrived on March 8th 2017. The officer didn't stamp on my passport with the date I should leave, but instead with the day that I arrived in Canada.

Can I renew my visitor visa? I am planning to go to the US in May and return to Canada a week later. I tried calling the CIC several times, but no agent was available.

Comment: Do you have a single or multi-entry visa to Canada?

Comment: i have a multiple entry visa but it will expire on april 14 2017

Comment: Sorry, Nicole, that was a stupid question on my part. Thank you for answering it.

Comment: so can someone please help me with as it is very important, i am just afraid when i ome back from the US, the canadian border won't let me in. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can apply [to extend your stay as a visitor](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp). If you passport is not stamped with the end date, [it means you have 6 month](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp), which is roughly September 8th 2017. You should apply no later then 30 days before the expiration date. The processing time for online application [is 58 days](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/index.asp), so I would advise to apply even earlier.

You can apply online or on paper [using the official Canadian immigration web site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend/visa.asp)

On the other hand, Canada used to have a little known rule similar to its US Automatic Visa Revalidation counterpart. Essentially, if you left Canada to the US (and only US), [you can come back on expired visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=527&top=16) within your original admission period.

PS.  I have traveled Canada<->US multiple times, but I have never used this particular provision when entering Canada. In the US the CBP officers are sometimes unaware of its counterpart, which resulted in lengthy delays on the border for me. If you decide to travel with an expired visa, make sure you are carrying with you at least the [relevant printout](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=527&top=16) from the Canada Immigration Services site.

Comment: Since Nicole is authorized to stay until September, and she's asking about a trip to the US in May, extension of status is entirely irrelevant. Anyway, she is not asking about extension of stay, but about getting a new visa for hernext planned entry.

Comment: Down voters, please explain. I don't get it :( Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. However, no I am just visiting my children in Canada and going to the US to visit some friends. So meaning if I leave the country to go back to my country with an expired visitor visa, there will be no problem with my status in Canada?

Comment: @NicoleFernandez, can you clarify what countries do you mean by "the country" and by "your country"? However, if you leave Canada to the US (and travel to no other country), you should be able to reenter Canada before Sept 8th per my last link.

Comment: @GayotFow the question is asking about a trip to the US from Canada after the expiration of the Canadian visa, but during the period of admission.  Extension of stay as a visitor concerns extending the period of admission, which does not help the situation described in the question.  The planned trip to the US already falls within the period of admission.  The problem is getting back into Canada after the visa has expired.  (Canada, like the US, requires visas to be valid only at the time of entry; the period of admission is not related to the visa's expiration date.)

Comment: @mzu So if i go back to Canada before Sept 8th, then when i go back to my country, which is Malaysia, will there be any problems when i pass thru the immigration?

Comment: @NicoleFernandez If you:
  1. leave Canada to US (I assume you have valid US visa)
  2. Do not travel anywhere else
  3. You can return to Canada by ~ Sept 8th
  4. and leave Canada by approximately Sept 8th
and there is nothing involving inadmissibility issues etc
you should be able to leave Canada with no problems.
Once again, this does not constitute a legal immigration advice and is for information purposes only.

Comment: @mzu thank you so much for the information! This helped me a lot. I have one more question, if ever i decided to stay later than the 8th sept in Canada and apply to extend my visitor visa in Canada, are they going to issue another visa sticker on my passport? I am planning to travel the whole north america while i am here. Might as well make my stay worth it.

Comment: @NicoleFernandez, I am not sure. It worth asking a new question. Brief research shows that: In order to apply for visa within Canada you have to be student or worker, not visitor. (http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/cpp-o-apply.asp). Extension of stay might not involve issuance of a separate visa sticker (as it is in the US).